# How to add items in a row type array from a plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist

I have a plist with the next structure:

```
-root (dictionary)
  -windows (array)
```

I need to add items into the row windows like this:

```
-root (dictionary)
  -windows (array)
    -item0 value 1
    -item1 value 2
```

I have these lines:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Windows.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    [data setObject:idWindow forKey:@"Windows"];

    [data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
```

But they only change the type of Window row to string and write the last value I insert.

How can I do this?

Tanks

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an NSMutableDictionary. So we get the array for key 'windows' like this:

```
NSMutableArray *windowsArray=[data objectForKey:@"windows"];
```

Then you can add to this array like this:

```
[windowsArray addObject:myString];
```

In your code when you do `[data setObject:idWindow forKey:@"Windows"];` you replace the whole windows array with the object idWindow. That is why you end up with just your final string.

The following is a complete code fragment that reads a plist from inside the application bundle, adds 2 strings in the windows array and saves it in documents directory:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EmptyWindows" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"data: %@", data);

NSMutableArray *windowsArray=[data objectForKey:@"windows"];
NSLog(@"windows: %@", windowsArray);

[windowsArray addObject:@"TestString1"];
[windowsArray addObject:@"TestString2"];
NSLog(@"windows after add: %@", windowsArray);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Windows.plist"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the lines you mention, to this: 'NSMutableArray *windowsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithArray:[data objectForKey:@"windows"]];',and in the part to write in the plist, I've changed for this '[windowsArray writeToFile: path atomically:YES];', but is not working fine, now it changes the root row to an Array, and keeps storing the last value I enter